# what is the different between Sharepoint fast search service and Sql server fulltext search?

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, full-text-search, fastsearch

I want to kow what is the different between Sharepoint fast search service and Sql server fulltext search?

Or Can I abstract the Sharepoint fast search from the Sharepoint platform as a isolate component?

Thank you.

David

Answer (score 0):

Well they have nothing in common and FAST is a search engine either implemented and integrated in SharePoint or used standalone. In SharePoint 2010 FAST was sold as an additional component while it is standard in SharePoint 2013. Microsoft purchased the company building FAST a couple of years ago and have kept some 70-80% of the technology in SharePoint 2013.

I believe you still can buy the FAST Search Server as a standalone product but would not quite understand why since the SharePoint version of FAST is way easier to work with.